# Can't reach servers, running on Raspberry PI, over OpenVPN connection

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry PI 2, running several servers (FTP, SSH, HTTP… etc).
I started using it as a wireless router (forward `tap0` connection to `wlan0`); [I used this great tutorial](http://www.daveconroy.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-router-and-web-server/). Everything is working great.

When I installed OpenVPN and connected to it, can share my VPN connection to Wi-Fi clients and it’s working well; can access to servers too. But using the VPN’s public IP, can’t connect to my servers but ping is working.

It might be some routing problem, but I can’t figure out what.

The routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.4.1.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tap0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         10.4.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    512    0        0 tap0
10.4.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
128.0.0.0       10.4.1.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tap0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.150.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
rxkk.vekoll.uni 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

Loaded IP table:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Oct  2 00:01:10 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [447645:303647899]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [31:2073]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [388590:80274564]
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tap0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tap0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct  2 00:01:10 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Fri Oct  2 00:01:10 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [11041:767122]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2671:258110]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [385:27556]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [253:17828]
-A POSTROUTING -o tap0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

I’d be happy if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

> But using the VPN’s public IP, can’t connect to my servers but ping is working.

Your public IPs are **not** part of your VPN .. you need to `port forward` the service ports of your services to the correct service IP address.

**This has nothing to do with your VPN**

Answer (score 0):

Finally, managed to solve this, it was too obvious.

The problem was this 2 lines:

```
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         10.4.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    512    0        0 tap0
```

The connection come in `tap0` interface, but the response is send to the lower metric interface, to `eth0`. Changing the default gateway solved my problem.

Comment: What about your 1st self answer ? It was correct or do you understand (how?) that it was not that?

Comment: I don't even know. I changed this, and solved my problem, but somehow a kernel update was the solution. Updated, and everything is working, with the same settings.

Comment: @Schzolee, what did you change the default gateway to ? Does this look similar to you : https://superuser.com/questions/1317976/raspberry-pi-as-access-point-with-vpn. I have updated the kernel, but that did not solve the problem for me.